# GitHub combine repos into third repo from webpage

Tags: git, github, wiki, github-pages

I have the following repository structure on GitHub:

```
DSL/preprocess/
DSL/postprocess/
```

In each of the folders `preprocess` and `postprocess`, I have a `Readme.md` and a Wiki...nothing else is in those folder (no code).

Now, since these repos are both for `DSL`, I am hoping to combine them into a new repository named `BriQBDSL`. However, I would like to to do this from the GitHub webpage.

**Additional Information:**

1. Since there is no code in either of the folders `preprocess` and `postprocess`, I am not concerned about history.
2. I can back up the Wiki pages (if needed - see below)
3. I'm working in Windows and don't have `git` installed (would prefer to avoid installing it).

**Main concern:**

My main concern is that the Wiki in both folders has quite a lot of subpages - backing up the pages would take some time. I would like to keep those pages intact during this proposed move.

Is it possible to combine these 2 repos into a new (third) repository named `BriQBDSL` through the website? If not, can this be done programmatically?

Comment: What format is the wiki in? Markdown? Could you just use git submodules (https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, the wiki is in Markdown.

Comment: StephenG: did you mean `git clone` to clone a project with submodules?

Comment: Personally, I've found useful to learn git in order to build nice things with github. [Some links here](https://help.github.com/articles/good-resources-for-learning-git-and-github/).

Comment: I agree. Just looking into it now. Looks handy too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use submodules.

Create your new repository.

Inside the new repository, put a `.gitmodules` file with the following content:

```
[submodule "DSL/preprocess"]
    path = DSL/preprocess
    url = {URL OF YOUR PREPROCESS REPO}
[submodule "DSL/postprocess"]
    path = DSL/postprocess
    url = {URL OF YOUR POSTPROCESS REPO}
```

Run `git submodule update --init` from the base directory of your new repository. (I'm not sure if GitHub has this command available through the web site)

Comment: Sorry, not too familiar with `git` commands - what would be the root directory in this case?

Comment: The base directory of your new repository - sorry, that wasn't clear.

Comment: Ah, so if the new repo I am planning to use is named `BriQBDSL`, then it would be `/BriQBDSL`, correct?

Comment: I'll likely accept this answer, however, one thing I found out before trying this is that GitHub does not allow a dedicated wiki page for sub-folders. If I were to have moved the 2 repos above into a single overall (higher level) folder, GitHub would have had trouble with the wikis of the 2 repos which I would have wanted to keep separate. I should have mentioned this in the original post.

Comment: You'll have 3 repositories - The parent, preprocess, and postprocess. Your two submodules will still be their own repositories so they can have separate wikis.